# how to make it so that $this->addCss adds https links instead of http

Tags: octobercms

In my myproject/themes/mytheme/layouts folder I have a file - default.htm - that reads like this:

```
description = "Default"
==
<?php
function onStart()
{
$this->addCss('/themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css');
$this->addCss('/themes/mytheme/assets/css/custom.css');
$this->addCss('/themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap-select.min.css');
}
?>
==
blah blah blah
```

The problem is that my website is being served up via https while the CSS links generated by `$this->addCss()` are being added with http (vs https).

How can I make it so that the generated links are https instead of http?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$this->addCss()` will detect automatically what to use `http` or `https` from current `scheme`.

> Still, if you face an issue you can tell OctoberCMS to use `https` using config.

`config/cms.php`

[image]

if any doubts please comment.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you will be satisfied with this connection option

```
<head>

...

<link href="{{ [
    'assets/css/bootstrap.min.css',
    'assets/css/custom.css',
    'themes/mytheme/assets/css/bootstrap-select.min.css',
]|theme }} rel="stylesheet">

...
</head>
```

You can also control this through your .env configuration